# Action for header in UICollectionView IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have different number of headers in a collection in my code and when I click a header each header has different actions. If I select a cell, `- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method is called. So, is there any delegate method which is called when any supplementary view is selected?

Comment: You can add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your view

Comment: thanks for help, but by using UITapGestureRecognizer i have to assign different function to different header, I want a one method which could be used for all headers by different indexpath, Is it possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to add a guesture to your view such as

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                               initWithTarget:self
                               action:@selector(handleTapGuesture)];

[headerView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Place this code where you setUp your HeaderView

and then implement the  -(void)handleTapGuesture; method to carry out your actions

Comment: thanks for help, but by using above method i have to assign different function to different header, I want a one method which could be used for all headers by different indexpath, Is it possible

Comment: then try passing Section No. int the method, and then keep chi according to the SectionNo.

Answer (score 9):

Here is [@Geet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24884506/4833705)'s answer for Swift 5. There are only 9 simple steps using a delegation

```
// 1. create a protocol outside of your headerView class
protocol YourHeaderViewDelegate: class {

    // 2. create a function that will do something when the header is tapped
    func doSomething()
}

class YourHeaderView: UICollectionReusableView {

    // 3. inside the headerView set a property named delegate of type YourHeaderViewDelegate? and make sure it's **weak**
    weak var delegate: YourHeaderViewDelegate?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        // 4. add a tapGesture to your headerView
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(headerViewTapped))
        addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    // 5. inside the selector method for the tapGestureRecognizer call the property and then call the doSomething method
    @objc func headerViewTapped() {

        delegate?.doSomething()
    }
}

// 6. make sure the class with the headerView's collectionView conforms to YourHeaderViewDelegate
class ClassWithCollectionView: YourHeaderViewDelegate {

    // 7. inside the class with your collectionView when you create the headerView make to set the delegate as self
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "headerViewId", for: indexPath) as! YourHeaderView
        
        // 8. *** set this to self ***
        headerView.delegate = self
        
        return headerView
    }

    // 9. since your class conforms to the YourHeaderViewDelegate method when you tap the headerView this function will get called
    func doSomething() {

        print("hello!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use closures to implement if you need use indexpath to do something.Acconding to @Geet's answer

```
class headerView: UICollectionReusableView {
    var headerDidSelected: (()->())?

    ...

    func handleTapGuesture() {
        self.headerDidSelected?()
    }
}

class viewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        
        let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "headerViewId", for: indexPath) as! headerView
        
        headerView.headerDidSelected = { [weak self] in
            print(indexPath)
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I liked your solution, nice and easy, it works for me. 
Got a warning on the [weak self] saying it was unused so I just removed it.